# Cannot read property 'lat' of null - leaflet.js error

Tags: javascript, wordpress, leaflet

!!Noob alert!! I am fetching data and placing it in the page as a json object - Latlng coords and some other data. (I realise that this may not be the best way to do this, but it had been working fine). I have a script then accessing the data, looping over it and adding markers based on the data. I am getting the above error from the leaflet.js file and have no idea what the problem is. Any help appreciated.

This is the code in the file that accesses the data and I believe is probably causing the issue.

window.onload = function() {

```
var energyIcon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: '/major_proj/wp-content/themes/customizr child/scripts/leaflet/images/marker-icon-green.png',
    iconRetinaUrl: '/major_proj/wp-content/themes/customizr child/scripts/leaflet/images/marker-icon-green-@2x.png',
    iconSize: [45, 55],
    iconAnchor: [19, 55],
    popupAnchor: [-2, -58],
    shadowUrl: '/major_proj/wp-content/themes/customizr child/scripts/leaflet/images/marker-shadow.png',
    shadowRetinaUrl: '/major_proj/wp-content/themes/customizr child/scripts/leaflet/images/marker-shadow-@2x.png',
    shadowSize: [0, 0],
    shadowAnchor: [45, 55]
});

var tourismIcon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: '/major_proj/wp-content/themes/customizr child/scripts/leaflet/images/marker-icon-yellow.png',
    iconRetinaUrl: '/major_proj/wp-content/themes/customizr child/scripts/leaflet/images/marker-icon-yellow-@2x.png',
    iconSize: [45, 55],
    iconAnchor: [19, 55],
    popupAnchor: [-2, -58],
    shadowUrl: '/major_proj/wp-content/themes/customizr child/scripts/leaflet/images/marker-shadow.png',
    shadowRetinaUrl: '/major_proj/wp-content/themes/customizr child/scripts/leaflet/images/marker-shadow-@2x.png',
    shadowSize: [0, 0],
    shadowAnchor: [45, 55]
});

var foodIcon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: '/major_proj/wp-content/themes/customizr child/scripts/leaflet/images/marker-icon-red.png',
    iconRetinaUrl: '/major_proj/wp-content/themes/customizr child/scripts/leaflet/images/marker-icon-red-@2x.png',
    iconSize: [45, 55],
    iconAnchor: [19, 55],
    popupAnchor: [-2, -58],
    shadowUrl: '/major_proj/wp-content/themes/customizr child/scripts/leaflet/images/marker-shadow.png',
    shadowRetinaUrl: '/major_proj/wp-content/themes/customizr child/scripts/leaflet/images/marker-shadow-@2x.png',
    shadowSize: [0, 0],
    shadowAnchor: [45, 55]
});

var map = new L.Map('map', {
    zoom: 12,
    center: new L.latLng(data[data.length - 1].loc) //set center from first location
});

map.addLayer(new L.TileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png')); //base layer

var markersLayer = new L.LayerGroup(); //layer contain searched elements
map.addLayer(markersLayer);

// ===== populate map with markers from sample data and give it a different icon depending on its 'type'

for (i in data) {

    var loc = data[i].latLng,       // position found
        title = data[i].title,      // type
        type = data[i].type;        // title
        //email = data[i].email;    // email

    if (data[i].type == "energy") {
        var marker = new L.Marker(new L.latLng(loc), {
            title: title,
            icon: energyIcon
        });
    } else if (data[i].type == "food") {
        var marker = new L.Marker(new L.latLng(loc), {
            title: title,
            icon: foodIcon
        });
    } else if (data[i].type == "tourism") {
        var marker = new L.Marker(new L.latLng(loc), {
            title: title,
            icon: tourismIcon
        });
    }

    marker.bindPopup(type);
    markersLayer.addLayer(marker);
}

/* inizialize search control */
map.addControl(new L.Control.Search({
    wrapper: 'findbox',
    layer: markersLayer,
    initial: false,
    collapsed: false
}));
```

}

Comment: The error should come with a specific line number that is generating it...

Comment: you should also paste in an extract from your "data" object.